# Where is SubtleCrypto's CryptoKey Stored?

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api, browser-security, subtlecrypto, webcrypto

I am currently utilizing the WebCrypto API, specifically SubtleCrypto. I store CryptoKey in IndexedDB and call it as needed. As far as I know, IndexedDB is a serialized database. If I can access IndexedDB from the disk, can I retrieve the CryptoKey through deserialization?

Someone told me that the actual CryptoKey isn't stored in IndexedDB, but the actual raw value is stored in a secure space within the browser. Is this accurate? Where exactly is the raw data of the actual CryptoKey stored?

I am interested in obtaining detailed information about CryptoKey for security purposes.

Thanks for reading the question.

I've been looking through various documents, but I haven't found the answer I'm looking for yet...

Comment: can you explain how you `store CryptoKey in IndexedDB` and what you mean by `call it` as needed? sample code in the question would be good